# Is there a way to create a database that can be accessed on a shared drive?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-connection, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to create a database that multiple people who have access to a shared drive can access. This is for a day long training so I am looking for a short-term solution. I would prefer not to use Microsoft Access if possible. I have looked into using Oracle SQL Developer or SQL server; however I have not been able to figure this out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think the database you're looking for is [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html). A database in SQLite is a single disk file.

> SQLite is a C-language library that implements a small, fast,
>   self-contained, high-reliability, full-featured, SQL database engine.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle SQL Developer isn't a database, just a tool you can use to access and use a database.

You could setup Oracle Express Edition (XE) for free on a Linux machine or VM, and as long as that machine has an IP address accessible from your users' machines - they could use SQL Developer to access it just fine.

XE is completely free. You just won't get more than 2 cpu's to run it and you'll be limited in terms of memory and disk space. [Details here](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/xe.html).